# Xs:pattern interpretation in XML

Tags: xml, lexical

How to interpret the following xml element?

```
xs:pattern value="[ !-~]*"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a regular expression pattern meaning that the element it applies to has to have in itself at least 0 characters of the following type: spaces and/or characters between ! and ~ (inclusive).

Thats all characters with ascii code with 32..126

Since space is just before ! u could also use `[ -~]*` instead

Comment: "characters between ! and ~" sounds like an ordered list of characters. Which list does this refer to? Can you point me to a link that has the info?

Comment: Yes, thats a set of characters http://www.danshort.com/ASCIImap/ characters with code 32..126